# Suppose $|G|=p^nm$ for prime $p$ s.t. $p\nmid m$. Suppose $\exists P\unlhd G$ of order $p^n$. Prove $f(P)=P$ for all automorphisms $f$ of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

I know this question has been asked here few days ago and someone suggested it is easily solved using Sylow's theorem. However this problem is from Herstein's book and it follows a chapter about cauchy's theorem. Does someone know more elementary proof. I was thinking that it is easy to prove that image of $P$ is normal subgroup, maybe it is possible to prove that $P$ is only normal subgroup of G of order $p^n$ or something like that.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: If you thinking about title, I used all characters so there wasn't any space for $ and stuff

Comment: Shaun thanks man

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Yes $P$ is the unique subgroup of order $p^n$. If there was another one, $Q$, then $PQ$ would be a subgroup of order $p^k$ for $k>n$, contradicting Lagrange's Theorem.